# Change date in a SQL query to reference a cell in Excel

Tags: sql, date, query

I have the following code that returns the needed data into excel and manually changing the date will change the returned data; however, I'd like to reference a cell with a formula that will make the query a bit more user friendly.

I've tried using my limited knowledge of referencing a cell but none have worked. This information is in cell `A1` and the query is placed in cell `A2` with the following equation: `=wwQuery("STKAP03", $A$1)`

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(INSQL, "SELECT DateTime, [40_MOTORS.MI436423.CIN], [40_MOTORS.MI436425.CIN]
FROM WideHistory
WHERE [40_MOTORS.MI436423.CIN] IS NOT NULL 
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
AND DateTime >='20120409 07:00:00' These two dates/times I'd like to reference cells on a different sheet
AND DateTime <= '20120416 07:00:00'")
```